# Connecting and querying two Mysql databases simultaneously with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I'm intending to develope a web that interacts with three different Mysql databases in the same server. User and password are the same in all three databases.
I want to use mysqli in procedural mode.
Some times I want to query just one databse, some times two of them, whatever.
What would it be the best way to connect with two of them and then, say, join two tables belonging to different databases?
Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the databases all reside in the same server, you can query any table in any database at any time that you have access to by prefixing it with the database name:

```
SELECT *
  FROM database1.table1
  JOIN database2.table2 ON ...
```

If the databases are on two different servers or need different access rights, there's no way to do this.

Comment: That way, doesn't it make any difference what database I connect to, before proceeding with the query?

Comment: @Rodolfo You're never actually connecting "to a database". You're just connecting to the *database server* and you *select a default database*. You don't technically need to select a database at all, you could be prefixing every table in every query. Selecting a database is mostly really a convenience feature to establish a default implied database in queries.